# Drawing marker on top of camera view with Google Vision API for Android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-vision

How can I draw shapes or graphics on top of the camera view with Google Vision API on Android?

Most barcode scanners I have seen so far have something like a blinking horizontal line in the middle of the screen to make focusing the barcode easier. However looking at the API reference I haven't found that yet.

Does Google Vision API have an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Read FaceTracker sample please. at onDraw() in FaceGraphic.java https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker